# I have no intention of making ghusl before i entered bathroom

Tags: ghusl

First of all im so sorry if the title of this is kinda confusing

So yesterday i decided that i will shower, and i have no intention to make ghusl, after i got inside the bathroom i suddenly think that i should make ghusl since i feel like i finished my period anymore. after i see my pads that it's just brown discharge, i decided that i will make ghusl so that i can fast tomorrow. now in a few minutes we will eat for suhoor.
Is my ghusl valid? or should i make ghusl again?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: Intention for ghusl is an obligation in the Maliki, Shafii, and Hanbali mazahib. Intention for ghusl is not necessary in the Hanafi mazhab. They say intention is only Sunnah.

Secondly: Making intention for ghusl before entering the bathroom is not necessary. Intention is enough as long as it is before the action itself (i.e. the action of ghusl).

In addition, if you are taking a bath and in the middle of it want to make the intention of ghusl, that is also fine if you redo all the requirements of ghusl after you make the intention.